# Recode values to a new variable using R

Tags: r, recode

I have a dataset with a variable that i need to change anonymise by recoding into a different variable.
There are 20,000 entries, some are duplicated so my data looks something like this:

```
DCD97568
DCD23547
DCD27656
DCD27656
DCD87590
```

The end product I want is a new variable that looks like this:

```
DCD00001
DCD00002
DCD00003
DCD00003
DCD00004
```

Thanks!

Update:

I need to deal with some NA entries in the original variable and I want these to be NA in the new variable so this

```
DCD14579
DCD21548
NA
DCD79131
DCD79131
DCD12313
```

would become

```
DCD00001
DCD00002
NA
DCD00003
DCD00003
DCD00004
```

Answer (score 3):

WE can do this with `sprintf` and `match`

```
df1$Col1 <- sprintf("DCD%05d", match(df1$Col1, unique(df1$Col1)))
df1$Col1
#[1] "DCD00001" "DCD00002" "DCD00003" "DCD00003" "DCD00004"
```

---

Or another option is `factor`

```
with(df1, sprintf("DCD%05d", as.integer(factor(Col1, levels = unique(Col1)))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("DCD97568", "DCD23547", "DCD27656", "DCD27656", 
"DCD87590")), .Names = "Col1", class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Nice idea using `sprintf`. I initially thought of the more convoluted: `df %>% mutate(V2 = paste0("DCD", formatC(group_indices_(., .dots = "V1"), width = 5, format = "d", flag = "0")))`

Comment: I've encountered an error when the original variable has an NA for an entry. The sprintf and rleid options, as below, produce a output in the sequence where the original is NA.  Is there a way to incorporate !is.na or similar?

Comment: @Nottles82  Please update your post with a new example and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` `rleid`, Thanks for some of the comments , **Assumption here is that the data is in sequence or it can be used once the data is sorted**:

```
x <- c("DCD97568",
       "DCD23547",
       "DCD27656",
       "DCD27656",
       "DCD87590")

new <- paste0("DCD000",data.table::rleid(x))

> new
[1] "DCD0001" "DCD0002" "DCD0003" "DCD0003"
[5] "DCD0004"
```

Comment: Another option is `rle` from `base R` although it is a bit unclear whether the OP meant for run-length or not

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your comments, I understood but I thought for this scenario it fits and your comments are always welcome. Always admired your answers.

Comment: This look a bit fragile when the `id` scales up. I think it won't pad the data in OP's format.

Comment: If not in sequence ,the table should be sorted for `rleid` to work correctly.